# create table at runtime in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can i create a table at runtime in Silverlight. In my project i am migrating from asp.net to Silverlight .
In asp.net i use Response.Write("");

In this way i generate a table . please let me know how i can generate a table in similar way at runtime in Silverlight ..

**Edit** Content from "answer"

My Grid has to look as shown below . I did this in asp.net using the response.write . any idea how can i achieve this in Silverlight .

Please find below how my datagrid should look . Is it possible please help .

```
  0    1    2     3    4   
Green red orange blue black
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a data grid?

Than you can create it using C# code constructing the object graph for a datagrid and than adding it to the view.

But perhaps you should better explain your question, why do you want to create a table at runtime?

Comment: My Grid has to look as shown below . I did this in asp.net using the response.write . any idea how can i achieve this in Silverlight .

Please find below how my datagrid should look . Is it possible please help .

0 1 2 3 4
Green red orange blue black